# Why is non-break space (&nbsp;) converting to a dash character (-)?

Tags: html, html-email, html-entities

I'm creating an HTML newsletter and I need to show some empty anchor links with specified height, width and block-level display, but [Gmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) seems to remove empty `<a>` links, so I put `&nbsp;` in links and it works like a charm but it renders `&nbsp;` as `-` character.

I checked both Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome and the problem exists in both browsers. Any ideas?

**Code Sample:**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="42" width="49" style="height: 42px; width: 49px"></td>
            <td height="42" width="123" style="height: 42px; width: 123px">
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/adsf" style="display: block; height: 42px; width: 123px">&nbsp;</a>
            </td>
            <td height="42" width="79" style="height: 42px; width: 79px">
                <a href="http://asdf.asdf.dsf" style="display: block; height: 42px; width: 79px">&nbsp;</a>
            </td>
            <td height="42" width="129" style="height: 42px; width: 129px">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/asdfasdf" style="display: block; height: 42px; width: 129px">&nbsp;</a>
            </td>
            <td height="42" width="111" style="height: 42px; width: 111px">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/adfdasff" style="display: block; height: 42px; width: 111px">&nbsp;</a>
            </td>
            <td height="42" width="269" style="height: 42px; width: 269px"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In fact, it has nothing to do with Gmail. The problem exists in my HTML project too.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Are you sure its not just the `text-decoration: underline` you are seeing on an empty space?  try adding `style="text-decoration: none;"` on those anchor tags.

Comment: Is this HTML for an email?

Comment: This is because empty links do not make sense at all... Imagine someone cannot display images (which I assume you have as bg?) - the link will be invisible to that person. This can be potentially malicious.

Comment: @Lowkase Yes it's for the image

Comment: @Christoph It doesn't matter! It's what they asked me to do!!

Comment: then put the image inside the anchor. This is semantically cleaner and makes a lot more sense than just an empty link..

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for your suggestion but I'm dealing with a stupid template which they gave me to implement and it's now long and complicated enough! I just want it to work in all mail clients, not making sense is not a problem here! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine the problem is that the space is underlined, like a link normally would be. You would have to set `text-decoration` to stop this.

As it is an HTML newsletter, I presume you want to do this inline:

```
<a style="text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have three solutions:

**1-** using `<br/>` inside your `<a>` element i.e :

```
<a href="#"><br/></a>
```

if you want to control the height of the element use this:

```
<a href="#" style="height:20px;overflow:hidden;"><br/></a>
```

**2-** using `text-decoration:none` with `&nbsp;`

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;</a>
```

**3-** using `text-indent` with `height` and `width`

```
<a href="#" style="text-indent:999px;width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: thanks but this will create a line break and my element heights wont be as what I want them.

Comment: @faridv define your height! `style="height:20px;"`

Comment: I did, you can see it my code, but Email clients render pages differently and to make sure it shows what I want it to show, I have to add more styles like `line-height` and `overflow` which I'm afraid because of huge code that I'm currently dealing with, is not a good solution. Because of both html size and lots of complicated code.

Comment: @faridv adding extra css codes define your page better than adding one code because every browser can render it with something different. I will edit and add more information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but remember mail clients have different limits on size of mail body. As I said, my HTML code is huge and it's now about 80kb. Google will cut down messages after 105kb.

Comment: And of course my problem was just about `text-decoration` and now it works like a charm! :D

Answer (score 1):

Add

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Or add inline:

```
<a href="path" style=" text-decoration: none;"> &nbsp; </a>
```

By default, anchor tags have `text-decoration: underline;`.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted but beware that some email clients like Gmail doesn't allow you to use css. All of your possibilities are using attributes or inline styles.